# Geocoding API Response Stops After 2,500 Requests

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I use the geocoding API to process lists of addresses using the 'geocoder' module in Python. As recently as a few weeks ago I was able to do this successfully, but today the API stopped responding after 2,500 calls. I did not get any error responses, and if I restarted the process I was able to get an additional 2,500 responses, but then nothing after that again. Does anyone know why this might be happening? The only reference to a cap at 2,500 was the daily free call limit on the previous pricing model.

[image]

edit: Interestingly, the issue seems to be isolated to my usage of the geocoder module. When I roll my own, I'm not having the same problem.

Function using geocoder:

```
def get_data(query):
    result = geocoder.google(query, key=apikey)
    return {'formatted_address':result.address, 
        'lat':result.lat, 
        'long':result.lng}
```

Function using just requests:

```
def get_data(query):
    try:
        api_response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+query+'&key='+apikey)
        read_response = api_response.json()
        address = read_response['results'][0]['formatted_address']
        lat = read_response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        lng = read_response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
        return {'formatted_address':address, 'lat':lat, 'lng':lng}
    except:
        return None
```

Worth noting that I'm on a new computer since the last successful run and I was running into some intermittent corporate firewall weirdness since I switched. It just seemed like such strange behavior for the issue to be on my side, I thought for sure I was running into an API limitation. I guess I will just log the issue on geocoder's git and move on.

Comment: May be it's your code capping at 2500. Hardcoded somewhere? Search for that as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter

```
rate_limit = False
```

in your your query. Thus your query above should be

```
result = geocoder.google(query, key=apikey, rate_limit=False)
```

Note: This works because the 'google.py' module by default calls the decorator

```
@ratelim.greedy(2500, 60 * 60 * 24) # Line 271 in google.py
```

So an alternative option would be to change that value in the source code.

Comment: Interesting. I can't find anything regarding that parameter in their documentation, how do you know to do this? I've already reverted to my own method using requests but when I get the chance I will try this out and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: I didn't see it anywhere in the documentation, but found it digging around in the geocoder source code here:  [link](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder/blob/master/geocoder/google.py)... look at the code beginning around lines 263 - 280.

Answer (score 1):

Google standard API usage limit is 2,500 free requests per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

If you want to increase your daily limit, you have to upgrade your API usage package from Billing console.

See [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing) for more information.